# Rotate Specified # of Views Results on a Time Based Schedule

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have 1000 results in a View Block. It contains a title and a teaser body. I want to be able to show 10 different results every week. How can this be done using Views? Or is there additional modules I would need?

Comment: you want this to be done automatically? Or would a changing a setting each week manually be ok?

Comment: would be automatically

Answer (score 1):

Not many answers so I'll add my two cents.. A week long cache for the view sounds like it could do the trick.

Comment: how would u do that?

Comment: In your view settings. Advanced>Other>Caching>Time-Based>Custom>604800 seconds.

I still don't know if it would definitely work but it's worth a try.